# Extending the Python Template strings

Tags: python, template-strings

Is it possible to extent the [Template strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#template-strings) so I can add methods to the identifier:

By default I can replace simple variables:

```
from string import Template
t = Template("${noun}ification")
t.substitute(dict(noun='Egg'))  # Output: 'Eggification'
```

But I wish to extend the identifier with a custom method (e.g. `as_b`):

```
t = Template("${noun.as_b}ification")  # Desired output: '<b>Egg</b>ification'
```

I know I can easily do something similar with [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#formatted-string-literals) but is it possible using the Template strings, like above?
I cannot use Formatted string literals because it will not work inside a script, a JSON file or whatever text that contain curly braces.

Essentially I'm looking for something that can offer the Template strings *syntax* within the Formatted string literals *flexibility*.

Comment: Why wouldn't you directly instanciate `t` as `Template("<b>${noun}</b>ification")`?

Comment: @vmonteco If `nouns` is a list, I can write `Template("${nouns.as_ul}")`; then the output is a big unordered list. Imagine `${nouns.as_ul}` inside an HTML template, I don't need some weird `{% for n in nouns %}<li>{{ n }}</li>{% endfor %}` but the method `as_ul` take care of it, nice and clean.

Comment: And what are you trying to achieve with all this? A web application?

Comment: @vmonteco For now just curiosity/studying but eventually a template engine. Even if they aren't so essential nowadays.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Genshi](https://github.com/edgewall/genshi) does exactly that but it doesn't seem to use the built-in `string` module.
Other useful references are [Chameleon](https://github.com/malthe/chameleon) and [Mako](https://github.com/zzzeek/mako).

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but I'd recommend not using Template strings.

If you're using Python 3.6 or newer, use f-strings:

```
def bold(t):
    return f"<b>{t}</b>"

noun = 'Egg'

print(f"{bold(noun)}ification")
```

when run:

```
<b>Egg</b>ification
```

If you'd rather a more powerful template mechanism, I highly recommend [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/).

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to do this myself, figured it out so came to update my google hit.

```
from string import Template
class MyTemplate(Template):
    idpattern = r'(?a:[_a-z][_.a-z0-9]*)'
    
s = MyTemplate("$myvar $my.var and ${myvar} and ${my.var}")
s.safe_substitute({'myvar': 'aaaa', 'my.var': 'bbbb'})
```

Result:

`'aaaa bbbb and aaaa and bbbb'`

Other over-ride options are both the `delimiter` (`$`) or `braceidpattern` (`None`) or `pattern`:

```
pattern = fr"""
{delim}(?:
  (?P<escaped>{delim})  |   # Escape sequence of two delimiters
  (?P<named>{id})       |   # delimiter and a Python identifier
  {{(?P<braced>{bid})}} |   # delimiter and a braced identifier
  (?P<invalid>)             # Other ill-formed delimiter exprs
)
"""
```